# Where can I find a good laptop for a SuperUser?

Tags: laptop, hardware-rec

I need help deciding on a good laptop model to replace a laptop that I overheated a "little" while letting it run a program for a week or two...

I am a Computer Programmer by trade, and an Engineering/Physics student (I'm doing a concurrent B.Sc/B.Eng).

I run Ubuntu Linux as an operating system, and the programs that I run with the heaviest requirements are:
Adobe CS6 Master Suite (Virtualized).
SolidWorks 2014 (Virtualized).
C++ Compilations and software  (Sometimes I write programs to solve Physics problems that run for weeks).
Skyrim.

My *needs* are:
RAM for multi-tasking. (I use 2-3 monitors, with the laptop screen).
Processor for those long...long computations.
15.6" screen. I hate tiny laptops.

My *wants* are:
Backlit keyboard.
Full keyboard with numerical keypad.
FHD Screen (1920x1080).

I do a lot of CAD and computations, and since I'm a student I'm always on the go.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: At the laptop store.

Comment: I tried that, they looked at me like I had two heads. Laptop store workers aren't exactly usually technically savvy.

Comment: Your question is formulated well and clearly, but asking for product recommendations is considered to be off-topic, as per http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Try chat for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a gaming laptop, it could use the graphics card for your CAD applications - usually gaming laptops have quite a bit of RAM as well.

You will probably need a laptop with Display Port out - or thunderbolt to handle more than one external screen effectively. You could get a usb 3.0 dock - if the laptop doesn't have those two options. But usb 3.0 diplay adaptors are still slow. With Displayport you can get 2x HDMI out adaptors. Thuderbolt will require a screen thats compatible (of which are usually awesome monitors).

ASUS do the ROG laptops which are big, heavy and powerful. Can hold lots of RAM... Alienware as well... lots of options for gaming laptops.